# What are the double union ($\Cup$) and double intersection ($\Cap$) Operators?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Finale of [THIS.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052300/meaning-of-strange-symbols)

Unicode says that $\Cup$ and $\Cap$ are double union and intersection, respectively. I was wondering if there was an actual operation that went with these symbols. If not, would these definitions make sense for these operators? As follows:

$$A\Cup B:=\left\{(x,x):x\in(A\cup B)\right\}$$
and
$$A\Cap B:=\left\{(x,x):x\in(A\cap B)\right\}$$

## Question

*Do these operators exist within Set Theory?* Iff not, do they exist *anywhere* in the realm of mathematics? Is my idea for these two operators logical and useful?

Comment: It would make more sense to define the double union as $\bigcup \bigcup A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a more useful definition would be $A\Cup B:=\{a\cup b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$, respectively $A\Cap B:=\{a\cap b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}$.
I've never seen the symbol before, but I could think of situations where that might be useful. I'm sure there are situations where the diagonal of $(A\cup B)^2$ (which you're using) is used, but I have no idea, when you'd want to introduce a special symbol for that, and why you'd want to pick one, that looks more like a union than a diagonal, which is usually denoted by $\Delta$...

Comment: So, let me get this straight: $A$ has to be a set, and each of its members has to be a set with sets as their children? An example of this would be great, if possible.

Comment: First, let me emphasize again, that I have never encountered those symbols before, but the way I understood your question you're just looking for plausible definitions, right?
Well, in axiomatic set theory, (almost) all sets have sets as their members, since all objects in set theory are sets - so the only set, that doesn't itself contain sets is the empty set.

Given that, I think a plausible way to define something that looks like a "double union" $A\Cup B$ would be, to take some union on the members of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, your definition of $\Cup$ would result in, when $A=\{1,2,3\},B=\{3,4,5\},C=\{7,8,9\},D=\{1,6,11\},E=\{A,B\},F=\{C,D\}$, then $E\Cup F=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11\}$?

Comment: No, in the definition I gave, $E\Cup F$ would be $\{A\cup C,A\cup D,B\cup C,B\cup D\}=\{\{1,2,3,7,8,9\},\{1,2,3,6,11\},\{3,4,5,7,8,9\},\{1,3,4,5,6,11\}\}$. The set you gave would be $\bigcup(E\cup F)$. But that's a meaningful definition as well, which I can imagine to be useful in certain situation. This more corresponds to what Martin Brandenburg suggested, i.e. $\bigcup\bigcup\{E,F\}$.

Comment: Ah, of course. I see it now.